# Farming Infernal Dye?

Tags: diablo-iii

I noticed that the infernal dye is really expensive in the auction house. I haven't found any so far in act 1 inferno... where can I find them and is there a specific location/trader/boss I can farm/look for them? Are they bound to a specific act/event in Inferno perhaps?

Comment: Pretty sure they're random. Try loading/reloading games in harder difficulties and checking out the dye vendors in different acts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you meet Arghus the Collector in Act 1 some NPCs have them. I sometimes find them and here is another [source](http://diablo3.gamona.de/database/infernal-dye-dye.html).